# XPath in PHP4 and value contents

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the contents of the XML:

```
$xmlstr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>
           <article>
             <Art>
               <test>Hello</test>
             </Art>
             <Another>
               <g>gooo</g>
             </Another>
           </article>";
$dom    =domxml_open_mem($xmlstr);


$calcX = &$dom->xpath_new_context();

$cnt = $calcX->xpath_eval($querystring);

foreach ($cnt->nodeset as $node)
{  
    print_r($node);

}
```

Is there a way that I can get the content when the querystring is //article/Art?

What I'm looking for is:

```
<test>Hello</test>
```

If I use $node->get_content(), then the result is Hello.

I'm working with PHP4, so I'm unable to use SimpleXML [which is PHP5]. $node is DOMElement.

$node->nodeValue causes:
Notice: Undefined property: nodeValue in .php on line 19

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple XPath expression that selects the wanted node(s). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile that I used the old PHP4 DOM extension, but try

- [`DomNode->dump_node` - Dumps a single node](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.domnode-dump-node.php)

Example:

```
foreach ($cnt->nodeset as $node) {  
    echo $node->dump_node; 
}
```

If the above doesn't do what you are looking for, try the other `dump_*` methods in `DomDocument`.

Comment: Dump_node requires a parameter, which isn't documented.

Comment: @monksy: Did you read the comments in linked documentation: *"`dump_node` is not a method of the `DomNode` class anymore but a method of `DomDocument` class. Note that `$dom->dump_node($myNodeObject);` also works in PHP 4.2"*

Comment: @monsky like I said, if the above doesnt work try the other dump_* methods, including the one suggested by Alejandro above.

Comment: Its dumping the last element name in the XPath as well.. is there a way to get only the contents within the path?

Comment: @monsky dump_node dumps the node you pass to it and return sit xml representaion. Your XPath //article/Art queries all Art elements, while you just want the child nodes of Art elements. Change the XPath to any of the two shown by Dimitre elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way that I can get the
>   content when the querystring is
>   //article/Art?
>
> What I'm looking for is:
>
> ```
> <test>Hello</test>
> ```

**Use**:

```
/article/Art/*
```

**This means**: Select all elements that are children of an `Art` element that is a child of the top element named `article` .

**If you want all nodes below `/article/Art`, use**:

```
/article/Art/node()
```

**This selects** all elements, text-nodes, comment nodes and processing-instruction nodes that are children of the top element named `article` .